# Building MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql

I am having a bit of a conundrum trying to build a database... I need some assistance.

I have 3 tables:

- Users (Username (PK) VARCHAR(30), Password VARCHAR(30), Profile (FK) INT, Admin TINYINT(1)
- Profiles (PId (PK) INT, Rate INT)

And my third table is what I'm having issues with.

- Jobs (JobId (PK) INT, Number VARCHAR(30), Title VARCHAR(30), [?????])

What I need to add to the Jobs table is each job has a different Rate for each profile. That'd be easy enough for a specific list of Profiles, but because we don't know how many Profiles there are, I can't add that to the Jobs table.

So how can I manage a variable amount of Profiles, that each have a different rate depending on the Job they are in?

---

Some Example Data:

```
 Users
+-------------------------------------------+
| Username  | Password  | Profile  | Admin  |
+-------------------------------------------+
| Admin     | *****     | 1        | 1      |
| Bob       | ******    | 2        | 0      |

 Profile
+------------------------+
| PId  | Name    | Rate  |
+------------------------+
| 1    | Admin   | 0     |
| 2    | Drafter | 10    |

 Jobs
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| JobId  | Number  | Title  | PId1  | PId2  | PId3  | ... |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 1      | 0001    | Job1   | 10    | 20    | 30    | ... |
| 2      | 0002    | Job2   | 20    | 40    | 60    | ... |
```

Because I don't know how many Profiles there are, I can't accommodate them in the Jobs table. So how can I fix this?

Comment: You need another table matching jobs to profiles.

Comment: Can you include some sample data the illustrates the variations.